# Remove matrix screen locker

Tags: remote-desktop, display, uninstall

I wonder if anyone here experienced problem with remote destop usage, when you try to take control of the server remotely, but the program like matrix screen locker doesn't let you to do it, even if you uninstall it and delete all (actually not all) the files, it still autoinstalls itself after reboot or some period of time.

How do I remove it totally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it is a malware. Does your anti virus software notifies anything. Is your patches upto date? Log into safe mode  and remove it. To log into the safe mode press f8 function key before the you see the windows image and after the BIOS loading is over.

Comment: thank you, i think this is malware too.. but still our antivirus Kaspersky is updated and official, but doesnt detect any viruses. for now this matrix screen locker is seems like uninstalled, but it probably changed the options of remote desktop somewhere, in the end the server is not accessible remotely, but while other functions of server works fine, the remote access doesnt work...